# How to make a local test server for an android app?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services

I basically need to create a test server, something that I can use locally to perform tasks for my application.

So my android app is basically a search engine, however the search queries will be made on the server and the results then fetched from the server on the mobile device as JSON objects.

Is there any way to replicate this functionality locally? I would just like to set up a server, include the Spring framework, the Google Custom Search API and develop it all in Java, then ship it to a live server directly when it's finished. (Most presumably a free tier Amazon AWS server, either EC2 or Lambda, not sure what the difference is).

Not quite sure where or how to get started so any help is appreciated, thank you!

p.s. I may try dabbling in some machine learning at a later date, but I don't know if this will affect anything, this will most likely be after I've got a live server up and running.

EDIT: Sorry, so how would I fetch data from a local server from my mobile device?  Do I need special software? Do I need to configure a local server? How can my mobile device fetch data from a second project when its being run on the first?

My app will fetch data from a server, so how can I create a dummy server, for it to fetch data from? Will I need to create a fully functioning online server, or can this just be done through creating a local server of some sort and then simply plugging my android device in and running the code? I have absolutely no idea how to test it without putting it online.

Comment: Run it locally like any other Java application that you would run locally? What is the actual issue you are encountering that you need help with?

Comment: You can use tomcat server. Use IP address of your system to connect to the server from android app. If you explain your problem we can suggest something.

Comment: You can also use Mockito to mock fake JSON responses in your test code.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a local installation of Tomcat server on your own machine.

Access the server by visiting "http://localhost:8080/" (or) http://127.0.0.1:8080". You can basically listening to your own local machine / host's 8080 port. Sometimes, it could be port 80 instead of 8080.

Please explore on how to host a Spring or Java application on a local server.

A good starting point would be to learn J2EE or Enterprise Java. You can configure Databases from your local installation.

If you opt for PHP as your language on server side, there is a pre-defined package called WAMP (for Windows), LAMP (for Linux), MAMP (for MAC) and XAMPP.
The above package are nothing but a package which contains a Server, Database and a Server side language usually PHP, if needed Python or Perl.

Please explain in which step you are getting issues so that anyone can help you exactly.